# Django: do SQL join for getting row count

Tags: django, django-models

In Django, I have a User model and a Following model:

```
  class User():
      uid = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True)

  class Following():
      follower_uid = models.ForeignKey(USER_MODEL, related_name="followers")
      followed_uid = models.ForeignKey(USER_MODEL, related_name="following")
```

with corresponding database tables for both object types.

When Django loads a User object, I want to also load the number of followers of that user in the same database query, i.e. using a join. What I don't want to do is load the user first and then do a second query to get the number of followers.

Is this possible using the Django object model or do I have to write raw sql?

I also want to load a second-degree count; that is, the number of followers of the followers of the user. As before, I want this count to be loaded in the same database query as the user itself.

Appreciate specific syntax and examples, I have read a ton of Django documentation and nothing seems to answer this. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

you can do this query:

```
from django.db.models import Count

>>> user = User.objects.filter(pk=some_id).annotate(num_followers=Count('followers'))

>>> user
[<User: someuser>]

>>> user[0].id
some_id

>>> user[0].num_followers
123
```

Comment: thanks, couple follow-ups:
1) how do i use `annotate()` if the obhect is coming from a OneToOneField?
2) is there a way to use `annotate()` to get second-degree follower count? e.g. the follower count of all the followers of the user?

Comment: follows ups should really be separate questions